# Did Gene Roddenberry ever react to 'Vulcans are Space Elves'?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, gene-roddenberry

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13956/120088), Gene Roddenberry wanted the Vulcans to look "satanic":

> From a behind the scenes perspective, prosthetic ears were easy to do, but also, Gene Roddenberry wanted a slightly satanic looking character.

Nontheless, a lot of people consider the Vulcans to be the Space Elves or ask if elves where an influence for Vulcans, see

- this [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/5ro54j/vulcans_are_space_elves_klingons_are_space_orcs/)
- this [question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Were-Vulcans-in-any-way-influenced-or-inspired-by-Middle-Earth-Elves)
- this [article on tvtropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceElves)
- this [post on The Omega Sector](http://theomegasector.com/index.php?/topic/19661-do-vulcans-elves/)

In the Wikipedia article [*Development of Spock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_Spock#Origins_and_%22The_Cage%22), it is quoted that Nimoy was unhappy about the elf jokes from the crew and that Roddenberry had to talk him out of leaving the show.

> Elf jokes from the crew were irritating Nimoy, and he complained to Roddenberry that the character could ruin his career and he no longer wanted to play Spock. Roddenberry talked him around, and Nimoy said to a journalist at the time that "Playing some monster or freak can be the kiss of death for an actor, and this emotionless guy with pointy ears from another planet just didn't appeal to me", but he and Roddenberry had "talked it over and agreed I wouldn't just be a walking computer who gives scientific data.

Did Gene Roddenberry ever react to that comparison, be it in an interview or privately and has been quoted? If so, what did he think of the comparison?

Comment: obligatory comment to encourage people to watch Nimoy singing the ballad of bilbo baggins.

Comment: @lucasbachmann What... how could I've missed that until now...